# Converting C# Razor view syntax to VB.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am new to Razor view syntax and as most of the examples are in C# I need help in coverting the below Razor syntax to vb.net

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <p>Your Name : @Html.TextBox("Name")</p>
        <p>Your Age Range : 
            @Html.DropDownList("IsEligibleAge", new[] {
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Below 18", Value = bool.FalseString},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "18 and Above", Value = bool.TrueString}
            }, "Please select your age")
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope it works:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())     
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        @<p>Your Name : @Html.TextBox("Name") </p>
        @<p>Your Age Range : 
            @Html.DropDownList("IsEligibleAge", { 
                New SelectListItem() With {.Text = "Below 18", .Value = Boolean.FalseString}, 
                New SelectListItem() With {.Text = "18 and Above", .Value = Boolean.TrueString}
            }, "Please select your age")
        </p>
        @<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" />
    end using
</div>
```

I used this good article about [Razor and VB.NET](http://jamisonwhite.com/2010/12/22/asp-net-razor-and-vb/) for the translation.

Comment: Thanks for the fix nemesv. And for the link

Comment: good article for the person who on vb.net and migrate from c# like me.